Laravel Nova - Belongs To Many Extended Form
Is there a way in laravel nova to extend the belongsToMany attach form to include addition fields.
I have a relationship between Courses and Members as well as a relationship between Courses and SignUpQuestions. Is there a way to create a form that will alow Members to be attached to the Courses, but also fill out all answers for any attached SignUpQuestions to the Course?
I attemped adding addition fields to the BelongsToMany relationship but since the question answers go into a seperate table than the pivot table this did not work.

Is there a way to create a form that will alow Members to be attached to the Courses, but also fill out all answers for any attached SignUpQuestions to the Course? >> Yes there is, but it requires you to load and store the individual components yourself. There is no built in way to store structures bigger than a model, so each related part should be saved by attaching it to the relationship.

Found my own answer - Yes you can, but you need to handle the values manually.
Here I attach a Member to a Course
 BelongsToMany::make(__('Members'), 'members', Member::class)
    ->fields(function () {
        return [
             Select::make('Primary Position', 'primary_position')
                 ->options($options)
                 ->rules('required', 'different:secondary_position'),
    
             Select::make('Secondary Position', 'secondary_position')
                 ->options($options)
                 ->rules('required', 'different:primary_position'),
         ];
    })

Then in the model function, I retrieve the attribute values:
public function save(array $options = array()) {
     $primary = $this->attributes['primary_position'];
     unset($this->attributes['primary_position'];
     $secondary = $this->attributes['secondary_position'];
     unset($this->attributes['secondary_position'];
     // Processing for SignUpQuestions
}

